# How do you add a description to a FAKE Target?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

Is it possible to add a description to this target? Or would I have to go about it another way?

```
Target "Test" (fun _ ->
    trace "Testing stuff..."
)
```

Edit:

[TargetHelper](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-targethelper.html) allows for the description to be shown when `listTargets()` is called.

At least, that's my understanding from the code here:
https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/TargetHelper.fs#L360-L365

Comment: What is the purpose of the description? How would it be used? Just as a comment for the developers, or in some other way?

Comment: see the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929989/is-there-an-option-to-list-the-targets-maybe-with-a-description-in-fake/39967435#39967435

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to make your build script readable, you can add a comment in the normal F# way:

```
// Tests some stuff
Target "Test" (fun _ ->
    trace "Testing stuff..."
)
```

As far as I know, there isn't anything built-in for adding descriptions to your targets in FAKE, but the nice thing about FAKE is that it is just an F# library, and so it is very customizable.

Here is one thing you could do - define your own function that wraps `Target`, but takes an additional description and builds a "Help" target with the descriptions automatically:

```
// The 'TargetDescr' function calls 'Target', but stores the description
let Description = System.Text.StringBuilder("Usage:\n")
let TargetDescr name comment f = 
  Description.AppendFormat(" * {0} - {1}\n", name, comment) |> ignore
  Target name f

// Now you can define targets using 'TargetDescr' and get help page for free!
TargetDescr "Test" "Tests some stuff..." (fun _ ->
    trace "Testing stuff..."
)

TargetDescr "Help" "Displays this help" (fun _ ->
  printfn "%O" Description
)
```

Comment: The target name is a string, give it a long name,
Target "Tests some stuff" (fun _ -> ())