# Is there an option to list the targets (maybe with a description) in fake?

Tags: f#-fake

In Ruby (RAKE) you can document your tasks in the following way

```
# rakefile
desc "cleans ./temp"
task :clean  do
  p :cleaning
end

desc "compile the source"
task :compile => :clean do
  p :compiling
end

$ rake -T # Display the tasks with descriptions, then exit.
rake clean    # cleans ./temp
rake compile  # compile the source
```

Is this possible with fake ?

Comment: Is it not similar to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017021/how-do-you-add-a-description-to-a-fake-target)?

Answer (score 2):

The same is implemented in FAKE, as I found out when reading the source

```
// build.fsx

Description "remove temp/"
Target "Clean" (fun _ ->
    CleanDirs [buildDir; deployDir]
)
// ....so on
```

Dependency graph is shown with  `.../fake.exe --listTargets` or  `-lt`

```
Available targets:
  - Clean  - remove temp/
     Depends on: []
  - Build
     Depends on: ["Clean"]
  - Deploy
     Depends on: ["Test"]
  - Test
     Depends on: ["Build"]
```